# do i miss anything to Parsing JSON in firebase

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am spend lot of time i can not figure out . why why it is not parse . 
[image]

```
func fetchUser(_ uid: String) {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("g373gSvDcFhXNAGh5V6vg7sU5C02").observe(.childAdded, with: {
        (snapshot) in
        //TODO...

        print(snapshot) //Snap (email) test1@gmail.com
        let user = snapshot.value as ? [String: Any]

        print(user) //nil

        if let _nameLabel = self.nameLabel,
            let name = user ? ["name"] as ? String {
                _nameLabel.text = "{-} \(name)"
            }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

You use the event type `.childAdded` for observing

> case childAdded is fired when a new child node is added to a location

**Solution:**

You should change the event type from `.childAdded` to `.value` like this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("g373gSvDcFhXNAGh5V6vg7sU5C02").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

  // other code

})
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do exactly with this formatting of the child? I mean when you access `snapshot.value` you have a dictionary of your firebase child and can access the key email and name. I really don't understand what you want to achieve with formatting the snapshot @cristanlika